# How to show a success message after PHP form submission?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, redirect, post

Here is the code. I want it this way --

Form submission --> page2.php --> redirect --> page1.php (Here is the message. Pop-up or whatever)

page1.php

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline subscribe-form">

                    <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Jack">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="sub" value="sub" >Submit</button>

            </form>
```

page2.php

```
    <?php
//include necessary

if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {

    $nameget = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect, $_POST['name']);
    $sqlentry = .....bla bla......//insert into DB
}

$getsql = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $);


if($getsql){
    mysql_close($dbconnect);
    header('location:page1.php');

}



?>
```

Comment: Maybe pass a success message via url to page1.php ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Where you have:

```
header('location:page1.php');
```

append a variable on the location, like:

```
header('location:page1.php?status=success');
```

And on page1.php, do something like:

```
if( $_GET['status'] == 'success'):
    echo 'feedback message goes here';
endif;
```

Comment: This is fine. It worked, thanks. But when I refresh the "page1.php?status=success" page, is there any way to head to "page1.php"?

Comment: Sure, depends on what you want.. maybe store the status in a session, or maybe just do a simple redirect with javascript, or display the feedback in a alert or modal window, that links to page1.php..

Answer (score 3):

This way your flash message will not show up again and again after refresh.

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']) && $_SESSION['msg'] != ''){
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline subscribe-form">

                    <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Jack">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="sub" value="sub" >Submit</button>    


           </form>
```

And

```
<?php
session_start();
//include necessary

if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {

    $nameget = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect, $_POST['name']);
    $sqlentry = .....bla bla......//insert into DB
}

$getsql = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $);
  if($getsql){
        mysql_close($dbconnect);
        $_SESSIOM['msg'] = 'Value Inserted or whatever';
        header('location:page1.php');        
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to unset the $_SESSION message else after page refresh it will still be there.

Comment: Also add in a check for $_SESSION['msg'] on the top with an isset() statement else it will throw an error!

Comment: Yes sure.. Added the same.

Comment: Edited your answer a little bit :)